# Python - itertools.product without using element more than once

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of lists, and I would like to duplicate the effect of `itertools.product()` without using any element more than once.

```
>>> list = [['A', 'B'], ['C', 'D'], ['A', 'B']]
>>> [''.join(e) for e in itertools.product(*list)]
['ACA', 'ACB', 'ADA', 'ADB', 'BCA', 'BCB', 'BDA', 'BDB']
>>> # Desired output: ['ACB', 'ADB', 'BCA', 'BDA']
```

The list I need to use this on is too large to compute `itertools.product` and remove the unneeded elements. (25 billion permutations from `itertools.product`, while my desired output only has ~500,000). Preferably, an answer will be iterable.

Edit: I know "product" is the wrong term for what I need, but I'm struggling to find the word I'm looking for.

Edit2: This is the list that I desire to perform this operation on:

```
[['A', 'H', 'L'], ['X', 'B', 'I'], ['Q', 'C', 'V'], ['D', 'N'], ['E', 'F'], ['E', 'F'], ['G'], ['A', 'H', 'L'], ['X', 'B', 'I'], ['W', 'U', 'J', 'K', 'M'], ['W', 'U', 'J', 'K', 'M'], ['A', 'H', 'L'], ['W', 'U', 'J', 'K', 'M'], ['D', 'N'], ['P', 'O', 'T'], ['P', 'O', 'T'], ['Q', 'C', 'V'], ['R'], ['S'], ['P', 'O', 'T'], ['W', 'U', 'J', 'K', 'M'], ['Q', 'C', 'V'], ['W', 'U', 'J', 'K', 'M'], ['X', 'B', 'I']]
```

Comment: It's not `product` you want to use, what you want is not a cartesian product.

Comment: @Olivier I know. See edit. What word should I use instead?

Comment: Do you need it for a more general case or only for this specific input?

Comment: @Olivier If "this specific input" is referring to my ugly requirement, then that's all I really need, but I'd prefer a general case if possible. I'll edit in the list that I need to perform this operation on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple stack-based implementation:

```
def product1(l): return product1_(l,0,[])
def product1_(l,i,buf):
  if i==len(l): yield buf
  else:
    for x in l[i]:
      if x not in buf:
        buf.append(x)
        yield from product1_(l,i+1,buf)
        buf.pop()
```

This is a bit slower than Patrick Haugh's answer (I get 18 s for your test case), but it gives the results in a predictable order.

Note that you have to process the values as it generates "them", since they're all the same list `buf`; you could write `yield tuple(buf)` or `yield "".join(buf)` to generate separate "cooked" values (at a cost of less than one additional second).

If the values are letters, you could use a "bitmask" list to implement the collision test, which reduces the time to about 13 s (but using a `set` is just as fast).  Other possible optimizations include processing lists with fewer eligible elements first, to reduce backtracking; this can get this case down to 11 s.

Answer (score 2):

```
test1 = [['A', 'B'], ['C', 'D'], ['A', 'B']]                                                                                           
test2 = [['A', 'H', 'L'], ['X', 'B', 'I'], ['Q', 'C', 'V'], ['D', 'N'], ['E', 'F'], ['E', 'F'], ['G'], ['A', 'H', 'L'],
         ['X', 'B', 'I'], ['W', 'U', 'J', 'K', 'M'], ['W', 'U', 'J', 'K', 'M'], ['A', 'H', 'L'],
         ['W', 'U', 'J', 'K', 'M'], ['D', 'N'], ['P', 'O', 'T'], ['P', 'O', 'T'], ['Q', 'C', 'V'], ['R'], ['S'],
         ['P', 'O', 'T'], ['W', 'U', 'J', 'K', 'M'], ['Q', 'C', 'V'], ['W', 'U', 'J', 'K', 'M'], ['X', 'B', 'I']]


def prod(curr, *others):
    if not others:
        for x in curr:
            yield {x} # (x,) for tuples
    else:
        for o in prod(*others):
            for c in curr:
                if c not in o:
                    yield {c, *o} # (c, *o) for tuples

print([''.join(x) for x in prod(*test1)])
# ['ABC', 'ABD', 'ABC', 'ABD'] 
print(sum(1 for x in prod(*test2)))
# 622080
```

The longer input takes about five seconds to run on my machine.  I use `set`s to pass values around because they are much more efficent than tuples or lists when it comes to membership checks.  If necessary, you can use tuples, it will just be slower.

Some questions to think about: does order matter?  What do you want to happen when we can't use an item from the current list (because they've all already been used)?

Comment: If all the elements have been used, you get nothing (e.g., if you pick A then B from [AB,BC,AB,XY]).  If this is inevitable (e.g., [AB,AB,AB]), the whole result is empty.

Answer (score 1):

Your specific case has an interesting property. If we arrange it in a counter, we see that every list occurs as many times as its entries:

```
Counter({('A', 'H', 'L'): 3,
         ('D', 'N'): 2,
         ('E', 'F'): 2,
         ('G',): 1,
         ('P', 'O', 'T'): 3,
         ('Q', 'C', 'V'): 3,
         ('R',): 1,
         ('S',): 1,
         ('W', 'U', 'J', 'K', 'M'): 5,
         ('X', 'B', 'I'): 3})
```

In other words, ignoring order, the sequences you want are the cartesian products of permutations of your lists. Suppose your list is called `l`. Then we can assemble a list of all the permutations of the sublists and take their product:

```
c = set(tuple(i) for i in l)
permutations = [list(itertools.permutations(i)) for i in c]
permutation_products = itertools.products(*permutations)
```

An element of `permutation_products` looks something like:

```
(('W', 'U', 'J', 'K', 'M'),
 ('E', 'F'),
 ('X', 'B', 'I'),
 ('Q', 'C', 'V'),
 ('P', 'O', 'T'),
 ('D', 'N'),
 ('G',),
 ('S',),
 ('R',),
 ('A', 'L', 'H'))
```

We have to get it back into the right order. Suppose our permutation is called `perm`. For each sublist of your list, we have to locate the correct element of `perm` and then take the next letter in the permutation. We can do this by making a dictionary:

```
perm_dict = {frozenset(p): list(p) for p in perm}
```

Then, to construct a single permutation, we have:

```
s = "".join([perm_dict[frozenset(i)].pop() for i in l])
```

We can combine all this into a generator:

```
def permute_list(l):
    c = set(tuple(i) for i in l)
    permutations = [list(itertools.permutations(i)) for i in c]
    permutation_products = itertools.product(*permutations)
    for perm in permutation_products:
        perm_dict = {frozenset(p): list(p) for p in perm}
        yield "".join([perm_dict[frozenset(i)].pop() for i in l])
```

Comment: This came in at 24s as written, and 14s if you leave the permutations as generators and don't convert to lists and create a list of `frozenset`s for the last line in advance.